# Not able to add/commit file in SVN using PUTTY Client

Tags: svn, putty

I am using Voyager repository, and PuTTY SSH client to access the repository. The SVN version on Voyager is `1.6.11(r934486) Compiled Aug 17 2015`. I have made some changes using PuTTY client. When I try to add/commit the changed file or even try to do `svn info`, it says

```
svn:'.' is not a working copy
```

How to commit file using PuTTY client? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You must use up-to-date Subversion client. SVN 1.6.x is not supported for several years and so does version 1.7.x. Use the latest SVN 1.9.x.
2. The error that you see should have nothing to do with PuTTY. The problem is that you try to perform `svn commit` operation, but you do not specify a correct path to the working copy. The current directory where you run `svn commit` is not a working copy.

Read the documentation:
[SVNBook | `svn commit` command line reference.](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.commit.html)